# IE11 - a "footer" at the bottom of the page that gets pushed down if height of content above is greater than height of window

Tags: html, css, flexbox, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I have implemented a "footer" that stays at the bottom of the page and gets pushed down if the height of the content above is greater than the height of the window. This works fine on Chrome, however IE11 doesn't push down the footer if the height of the content above is greater than the height of the window. IE11 just lets the content overflow the footer:

[image]

This is the fiddle of the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6zrk5adu/2/

The way I've implemented this is just an upper flex container:

```
.upper-flex-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

And a lower flex container for the footer:

```
.build-version-flex-container {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 75px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

What can I change for this to work and can this flex layout even work in IE11 at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out changing the css of upper flex container as follows:

```
.upper-flex-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

solves the issue. Not fully sure why though, seems to be IE11 specific.

https://jsfiddle.net/4xtjw35k/4/